# SQL Server Trigger on Deleted - Which records are in deleted table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to triggers, but I'm having a hard time understanding if I'm taking the right approach here.

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I have 2 tables, `Teams` and `TeamMembers`. `Teams` is the parent table and `TeamMembers` is the child, using `Teams.TeamID` as a foreign key.

I also have an `Activities` table that logs any creates or updates to any of my tables. This table has a `TableName` text column as well as an `IdRow` column that references the ID of the row that gets created or updated. I've also got a `JSONChanges` column which contains a JSON string of what was changed in that activity log item.

So there's only 1 record for each `Activity` on a table. But potentially many activities performed per record.

So, when a user deletes a team, I need to not only delete all of the `Activities` logged for that team and the Team Members for that team (which is easy to do within my `Team_Delete` stored procedure), but I also want to delete any records in my `Activities` table for the activities on the `TeamMembers`. Since the `Activities` table's `IdRow` column points at the `TeamMemberID` column in the `TeamMembers` table, I can't use the `TeamID` from the delete stored procedure.

My thought was to just create a delete trigger on the `TeamMembers` table.

Whenever a `TeamMember` was deleted, I could just delete all of the records in the `Activities` log that point to the record that was deleted. That would simplify my `Team_DELETE` stored procedure. I think.

The confusion I have has to do with the records that will be in the deleted table at any given time. If User A deletes a TeamMember, and at the same time, User B runs an Update on another Team Member, won't the deleted table have 2 records in it?  If I delete all records in my Activities Table based on what's in the deleted table, then I'm deleting records I shouldn't be deleting.  Right?

The other issue is how do I pick just one record to delete? How do I know which record in the deleted table is the one I want from the trigger?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post that will help you refine your question in a way that is more likely to be answered.

Comment: the only records in the deleted table are ones that are deleted in a single batch. If multiple rows were deleted, then the deleted table will hold all of the records that were deleted. You can join from the deleted table into your other tables to determine what else should be deleted as well. check out this article showing how you can limit deletes and updates with joins. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56823/delete-update-rows-using-inner-join-sql-server/

Comment: Do you enforce referential integrity with foreign keys between your tables (this seems like a situation where you should)?  If so, you can add 'On Delete Cascade ' and SQL server will handle these deletes for you, no triggers needed.

Comment: I did between the Teams and TeamMembers, but not on the Activities table which is where i"m trying to delete from.  The IdRow column points at the primary key field of any table in the database.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the role of the `Activities` table. It's keyed off of `TableName` and `IdRow`, where the `IdRow` is the id value from that table? You might consider having a distinct activities table per base table. Then you can use a foreign key between the two with `on delete cascade` specified. Then, when you delete something from the referenced table, it automaticlaly gets deleted from the referencing table.

Comment: The intent of the Activities table is to have a single table that logs all of the create and update activities for all of the tables.  There's a field for JSONChanges we can view the changes made per activity record.

Having a log table for every table in the database seems to me to be quite a bit of extra work and complexity both on the database and my webAPI where I'm exposing this data.

I was hoping for a simple solution that could offer reusable triggers or code because this will need to be accounted for many times in the development of this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to use a trigger on TeamMembers , I would try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name .]DeleteTeamMemberActivities ON [ schema_name .]TeamMembers
AFTER DELETE   
AS 
 DELETE   
 FROM 
    Activities a 
    INNER JOIN DELETED d ON d.TeamMemberID = a.IdRow AND a.TableName ='TeamMembers';
```

I would also use the cascading delete on the foreign key relation between Team and TeamMembers.

[edited 08/09/2017 12:45 correcting the a.TableName join]

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I edited cclarke's code a little bit - here's what I ended up with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_DeleteTeamMemberActivities ON TeamMembers
AFTER DELETE   
AS 
 DELETE a
 FROM 
    Activities a 
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.TeamMemberID = a.IDRow AND a.TableName 
    ='TeamMembers';
```